# if and else format? php

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. When it checks if the user is activated on line 26 even if the user is activated it sends the user to line 38 which tells tells them their username or password is incorrect but they are correct. You can find the two lines on the left side of the code.

```
   <?php
      require("includes/inc.php");
      if ($_SESSION['username'] != null){
        # Redirect the user to the member area
        header('Location: member.php');
      } else {
        # Check if the user is trying to login
        if ($_GET['do'] == "login"){
          # If they are, process the details they have provided. Else, continue with showing the form
          $username = trim(sanitize($_POST['username']));
          $password = trim(sanitize($_POST['password']));
          # Check if the username and password are empty
          if (($username == null) || ($password == null)){
            header('Location: login.php?error=field_blank');
          } else {
            $query_accounts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1");
            $query_count = mysql_num_rows($query_accounts);
            if ($query_count == null){
              // User not found
              header('Location: login.php?error=details_wrong');
            } else {
//Line 26          $active = mysql_fetch_array($query_accounts);
                if ($active['active'] == 0) {
                    header('Location: login.php?error=activate');
                } else {
                   $accounts = mysql_fetch_array($query_accounts);
                    // Check if the password matches the user's password
                     if ($accounts[password] == password($password)){
                    // The password is correct, start a session for the user
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        header('Location: member.php');
                    } else {
                    // Incorrect password
//Line 38                   header('Location: login.php?error=details_wrong');
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>PHP Login & Registration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <div id="main">  
    <h1>Login</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        Need a account? <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <!-- Display Messages -->
        <?php
          # -> Messages
          if ($_GET['error'] == "field_blank"){ echo "<div class='error'>The username and/or password field was left blank</div>\n"; }
          elseif ($_GET['error'] == "details_wrong"){ echo "<div class='error'>The username and/or password was incorrect</div>\n"; }
          elseif ($_GET['error'] == "activate"){ echo "<div class='error'>Please activate your account.</div>\n"; }
          elseif ($_GET['success'] == "logout"){ echo "<div class='success'>You are now logged out</div>\n"; }
          elseif ($_GET['success'] == "complete"){ echo "<div class='success'>You are now registered, please activate your account by visiting your email.\n"; }
        ?>

          <!-- Login Form -->
          <form action="?do=login" method="post" autocomplete="on">
            <fieldset>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" size="40" maxlength="20" /> <br />
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" size="40" maxlength="30" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" style="width:80px;" />
            </fieldset>
        <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
          </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
        } // End Check Login
      } // End check if logged in
    ?>
```

Comment: SIMPLIFY! Simplify, simplify, simplify! Having half a dozen levels of nested if-elses is simply too complicated.

Comment: Two problems I see, is should be $accounts['password'] NOT $accounts[password] (line 32), Also shouldn't it be $query_count == 0, NOT $query_count == null (line 22)

Comment: @jezternz Doesn't 0 equal null?

Comment: @Ahatius - In PHP it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have problem with `$accounts = mysql_fetch_array($query_accounts);`

$accounts is array that contain row and column as index you need to use while

```
while($accounts = mysql_fetch_array($query_accounts))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that stands out to me right off the bat, is the following line

```
                 if ($accounts[password] == password($password)){
```

The key will be translated into a PHP constant, which to my best guess looking at your code, has not been defined. Wrap the key in quotations, like the following.

```
                 if ($accounts["password"] == password($password)){
```

I hope that helps solve your issue :)

Comment: I didn't even see that thank you but that didn't help with my issue.

Comment: anyways in the codes that was given.. there is no code for connecting in the database... no connection strings...

Comment: So what exactly is the error you're getting? Are they being redirected to a page they're not supposed to be redirected to? Beauty in the details, if you tell me the symptoms, I'll tell you the issue :)

Comment: @Mahan I'd guess it's in a parent script.

Comment: Yeah, they are going to be redirected to the members page but before that it checks the username,password, and if the account is activated. The problem I'm having is that even though the account is activated the user gets the sent error message that the username or password is incorrect but they are. The user should be redirected to the members page but instead they are not.

Comment: Please try this, "$query_accounts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());" and tell me if any errors appear

Comment: How is your password in the database stored, and what does your password() function do when you've established the if statement mentioned in my answer? If the password in the database is plain text, then password($password) could be your issue

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

a) You get the row twice  (Line 26 $active = mysql_fetch_array($query_accounts); and just below $accounts = mysql_fetch_array($query_accounts);  - this may give you two different rows, when really there may be only one match - each "fetch" moves the pointer down a row

b) Check your variable type.

i) mysql_num_rows returns integer, but you're comparing to null

ii) also check $row['active'] is returning an value 0 and not a string null or blank. Might be safer to check for the negatives in both cases, i.e.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    if ($row['active']) {
        // active state
    } else {
        // inactive state
    }
} else {
    // Not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only solution is to simplify! This:

```
if (...) {
    if (...) {
        if (...) {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

is much better expressed as:

```
if ($someImportantCondition == false) {
    die('Important condition not met');
}

...

if ($someOtherImportantCondition == false) {
   die('Some other important condition not met');
}

...

echo 'Success!';
```

Instead of just `die`ing, you could display errors, redirect using `header`, `include` error pages, `return` from a function or whatever else you need to do that *stops* the logic at that point. Get that flow into a form a normal human can comprehend, then your problems will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I use the notation

```
if (...)
{
   if (...)
   {
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      ...
   }

}
else
{
   ...   

}
```

You can then easily identify what `else` part matches the `if` bit.

If you do this with your code you can find out what is going wrong.